# FireBase CellView Messaging

Tags: ios, firebase, messaging

As it stands right now users can register a username and password, and it correctly registers with my firebase. Tapping login with nothing enter allows an anonymous user. However after sign in it brings you to a group chat, where everyone is typing in basically a large chat room. Anymore than 10 people in there it would be chaotic to say the least.

I think the issue lies in here?

```
    private func observeMessages() {

    let messagesQuery = messageRef.queryLimitedToLast(25)

    messagesQuery.observeEventType(.ChildAdded) { (snapshot: FDataSnapshot!) in

        let id = snapshot.value["senderId"] as! String
        let text = snapshot.value["text"] as! String

        self.addMessage(id, text: text)

        self.finishReceivingMessage()
    }
```

This is my first really experience with a backend such as FireBase. Wouldn't it then only allow you to talk to one other person?

Or do I have to add another Controller with a cell view to display the different chat sessions ( like the native iOS messenger)

Is this what your looking for?

```
    {
  "messages" : {
    "-KHQAJGo3m78smQV-7p8" : {
      "senderId" : "7bdc0969-b2ad-4273-a1da-0b3fc4833c10",
      "text" : "Test"
    },
    "-KHQAPMujDpUOrfcghS9" : {
      "senderId" : "7bdc0969-b2ad-4273-a1da-0b3fc4833c10",
      "text" : "What\nIs \nGoing on"
    },
    "-KHQAu88NghIScIw3OPL" : {
      "senderId" : "fcc1c883-09c5-4c72-9e4e-3a9a745909a6",
      "text" : "The gab shook"
    },
    "-KHQAv8G1OH6nN2m1LvW" : {
      "senderId" : "fcc1c883-09c5-4c72-9e4e-3a9a745909a6",
      "text" : "Haha"
    },
    "-KHQAwK9i4gIp6PkPIZl" : {
      "senderId" : "fcc1c883-09c5-4c72-9e4e-3a9a745909a6",
      "text" : "What!"
    },
    "-KHQBx6o-jMn_8mxRCuu" : {
      "senderId" : "14ef0bf5-15c2-4f20-baf1-b2a58518932f",
      "text" : "Hhhhh"
    },
    "-KHQDOiNU2LAqSecFKf2" : {
      "senderId" : "549572b6-24ec-4de6-806f-db6e350c24fe",
      "text" : "Ggg"
    },
    "-KHQEcT9LyQl0VrO-kzY" : {
      "senderId" : "810fda99-8214-44d8-9192-69208a8404a3",
      "text" : "Why is there no indicator"
    },
    "-KHQEdr_3ei9D_Ang6yY" : {
      "senderId" : "810fda99-8214-44d8-9192-69208a8404a3",
      "text" : "Oh there it is"
    },
    "-KHQEigc7AA0lrd-6gvn" : {
      "senderId" : "810fda99-8214-44d8-9192-69208a8404a3",
      "text" : "Omg"
    },
    "-KHQEk88QFGWTyhBHlJc" : {
      "senderId" : "549572b6-24ec-4de6-806f-db6e350c24fe",
      "text" : "Sweet"
    },
    "-KHQEtuMw7C7ZIRfqtvV" : {
      "senderId" : "549572b6-24ec-4de6-806f-db6e350c24fe",
      "text" : "Now we can text each other"
    },
    "-KHQEwJlF-ejfH3QntLx" : {
      "senderId" : "549572b6-24ec-4de6-806f-db6e350c24fe",
      "text" : "So COOL! =)"
    },
    "-KHQExUTfOl1S1uNXhr0" : {
      "senderId" : "810fda99-8214-44d8-9192-69208a8404a3",
      "text" : "That's awesome!"
    },
    "-KHQF-3WUjiWd7PlW9lW" : {
      "senderId" : "549572b6-24ec-4de6-806f-db6e350c24fe",
      "text" : "Uh oh"
    },
    "-KHQF57qctPHTRsFIWz4" : {
      "senderId" : "810fda99-8214-44d8-9192-69208a8404a3",
      "text" : "Your actually texting me, holy shit"
    },
    "-KHQF7DcRRB8JyJwQFH5" : {
      "senderId" : "549572b6-24ec-4de6-806f-db6e350c24fe",
      "text" : "Stupid\n\nImagine if 100000 people were in here...would be chaos"
    },
    "-KHQF9vXLZNeKOvX8T0I" : {
      "senderId" : "549572b6-24ec-4de6-806f-db6e350c24fe",
      "text" : "Don't get excited exiting simulator now"
    },
    "-KHQFBU1THZe1x1wUeEx" : {
      "senderId" : "549572b6-24ec-4de6-806f-db6e350c24fe",
      "text" : "Good Bye"
    },
    "-KHQFBj5EpvrnDd4PCJb" : {
      "senderId" : "810fda99-8214-44d8-9192-69208a8404a3",
      "text" : "Figures"
    },
    "-KHQXXd0YWvKgD9iN9-u" : {
      "senderId" : "30f0983b-4dc8-4cc7-92ff-e9585f2ffe86",
      "text" : "Hmm"
    },
    "-KHQXaiuIg0eLb0d5f3Y" : {
      "senderId" : "30f0983b-4dc8-4cc7-92ff-e9585f2ffe86",
      "text" : "Ugh"
    },
    "-KHQXg-dzVL2vmltAwf2" : {
      "senderId" : "30f0983b-4dc8-4cc7-92ff-e9585f2ffe86",
      "text" : "Just"
    },
    "-KHQXo3MTZmlGTzUYitR" : {
      "senderId" : "73383e6c-3123-437c-b11e-51f0b35444a8",
      "text" : "What"
    }
  },
  "typingIndicator" : {
    "30f0983b-4dc8-4cc7-92ff-e9585f2ffe86" : false,
    "73383e6c-3123-437c-b11e-51f0b35444a8" : false
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you clearly define what the actual issue is? We would also need a sample of your Firebase structure as text (no images please!) Firebase Dashboard->Export button, then copy and paste it into your question. The code you posted could work in a variety of ways but there's not enough of it to know what you are trying to do.

Comment: The issue is ** that everyone signing in would be in the same chat room. There isn't separate sections of conversations.

Comment: What's your plan/code for allowing a user that just signed in to select a chat room? In other words, when you were laying out the app before starting to code, what step follows logging in? As it is, all of the users will see the messages in this 'room'. One option would be to simply allow the user to select a chat room in the ui; that then adds another level. So instead of root_ref/main_chat_room, it would allow you to have root_ref/main_chat_room/room_1  or /room_2 etc. Remember though, with Firebase the flatter the better so you should carefully consider keeping data as shallow as possible.

Comment: As it sits right now, a user signs in and is immediately directed to this chat room. Would Firebase be able to handle this: (this is how I would like for it to work anyway) *8User Signs In** Then is presented a table view of all the different conversations they are having** clicking on one brings up the conversation ((send, receive, blah blah)) back button to go back to table view. Add in user profiles done.

Comment: Yep - easily. Most of that is handled by the UI on the front coupled with a  good Firebase structure.

Comment: But this brings me back to the original problem.. how to restrict the conversation to just the two recipients.

Comment: We can't write the code for you but there's some examples on the Firebase website (see Firechat). Keep in mind that Firebase has no concept of Rooms or recipients; it's up to you to code that. But consider this; if you have a node called /room_1 and there are two child nodes: user_0: true and user_1 true, and user_0 and user_1 only observe /room_x nodes that have their user id's a children (set to true), that would limit what they see to only those rooms.